# How to make download file link to open form and mail the download link to email?

Tags: views, 7, files

**My flow is like that.**

1. I have scroll-able list of download links for Private files.
2. When user click on Download File link it will show Form to gather
   some data like first_name, last_name, email and Phone.
3. after submission Link will be forward to email Id specified in form
   with KEY will check Once download the file link will be expire.
4. Second Mail goes to admin and Data will be stored to system as Sales
   Lead.
5. File will be get to User.

I have created Views to List all the Files as a Block and  Link added to download file using yourdomain.com/get/file/1

Is there any suggestion for that or specific module tutorial available so, I can check...

Answer (score 1):

There is simple solution for this.

You need to create a `form` using custom module and link `download file` with that form. When user click on `download file` link, it will redirect user to form.

In the `form submit`, you can send mail to client with download link and admin also and can perform other task too.

If you want to expire `download` link after once download, you can save the counter of `download` in `database`. You need to create `link` for download in your custom module and in `page callback` of that link, you can check if its already downloaded or not.